# Why selecting unique occurrences after sorting holds different results than just selecting unique occurrences?

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

Why the output of

```
uniq | wc -l
```

is different from

```
sort | uniq | wc -l
```

which one is truly holding unique occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It explains the behavior in the **[`uniq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html)** manual page, in particular:

> <sub>By default, uniq prints its input lines, except that it discards all
>   but the first of adjacent repeated lines, so that no output lines are
>   repeated. Optionally, it can instead discard lines that are not
>   repeated, or all repeated lines.</sub>
>
> <sub>The input need not be sorted, but repeated input lines are detected
>   only if they are adjacent. If you want to discard non-adjacent
>   duplicate lines, perhaps you want to use **[`sort -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation)**. ( See sort invocation )</sub>

By not using `sort` ahead of `uniq` with the input there is not an accurate count of unique items.